# Хочу полностью удалить ruby и ruby on rails с linux mint(a) и установить с чистого листа

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Вес день мучаюсь вот что у у меня получилась, походу я не удалил его полностью и собираюсь снова установить и тут возникают проблемы. RVM выдает следующее предупреждение

> WARNING: Please be aware that you just installed a ruby that is no
>   longer maintained (2016-02-24), for a list of maintained rubies visit:
>   bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby/wiki/ReleaseEngineering Please
>   consider upgrading to ruby-2.3.0 which will have all of the latest
>   security patches.

Comment: Опишите подробнее как ставили? Через rvm?

Comment: Да через rvm но вот здесь на что ругается
WARNING: Please be aware that you just installed a ruby that is no longer maintained (2016-02-24), for a list of maintained rubies visit:

    http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby/wiki/ReleaseEngineering

Please consider upgrading to ruby-2.3.0 which will have all of the latest security patches.

Comment: rvm позволяет устанавливать несколько версий ruby и для каждого из них держит свой набор гемов. Может вам просто установить 2.3.1 и переключиться на него? Обычно rvm и ruby не сносят, а просто устанавливают все версии, какие нужны для работы - их может быть много, одному проекту нужно 1.9.3, другому 2.0.0, третьему 2.1.0, четвертому - 2.3.1. rvm позволяет установить и одновременно использовать все версии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если установка осуществлялась через rvm, достаточно удалить папку .rvm  домашней директории

```
rm -rf ~/.rvm
```

Кроме того, следует проверить файлы ~/.bashrc и ~/.bash_profile в домашней директории и удалить следующие строки, если они имеются

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
```

Comment: А эти файлы полностью удалил случайно

Comment: Не очень понятно, какие файлы? У нас нет возможности посмотреть вашу консоль, чем больше вы сообщите о том, что у вас происходит, тем отвечающим будет проще посоветовать что-то конкретное. Пока не понятно, у вас работает rvm? Например rvm list known? У вас работает ruby? Например ruby -v? Пожалуйста опишите проблему более продробно, не стесняйтесь дополнять свой вопрос - его можно редактировать.

Comment: Вот ссылка https://pp.vk.me/c636829/v636829989/12c85/LV92Tqaz1qY.jpg

Answer (score 4):

`rvm --help` ясно показывает, как его удалить:

```
implode     :: (seppuku) removes the rvm installation completely.

               This means everything in $rvm_path (~/.rvm || /usr/local/rvm).

               This does not touch your profiles. However, this means that you
               must manually clean up your profiles and remove the lines which
               source RVM.
```

То есть, сам RVM отпиливается одной командой:

```
rvm implode
```

Это сотрёт все установленные в его рамках интерпретаторы, гемы и исходники расширений. Плюс потребуется небольшая зачистка файлов конфигурации шеллов (`.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, `.zshrc` и т. п.) вручную от строчек, в которых упоминается RVM.

---

Если вас ещё угораздило установить `ruby`, `rubygems` или ещё что-то относящееся к Ruby из системных репозиториев... Оставьте. RVM позволит вам переключаться на системный Ruby при необходимости, он вам не помешает.

Но если всё же мешает, сотрите его через Synaptic, он есть в системе по умолчанию. Скорее всего хватит "полного удаления" (purge) пакетов `ruby` и `rubygems`. При удалении придётся стереть все зависящие пакеты, и процесс удаления попросит на это подтверждения. Просмотрите список на предмет того, нет ли там чего нужного.

Всё, заходите на [сайт RVM](http://rvm.io/) и следуйте инструкциям по установке RVM оттуда.

Answer (score -1):

Вот так:

```
sudo apt-get purge ruby
```

Comment: Так она полностью не удаляется остаются файлы

Comment: Да все исправил всем огромное спасибо. Вот еще один вопрос, а что будет если файлы ~/.bashrc и ~/.bash_profile в домашней директории вообще нет

Comment: Подсветка в консоли пропадет, могут не работать некоторые программы, если они туда что-то записывали. Лучше восстановить хотя бы оригинальные файлы для вашего дистрибутива. Задайте новый вопрос, на SO не приветствуется решение нескольких проблем в рамках одного вопроса.

Comment: А как восстановить не подскажете

Comment: @РасуловГамзат, да вы задайте новый вопрос - соберете гораздо больше ответов, чем в комментарии к ответу на вопрос, который не относится к Linux/Mint